# How to set zooming controls to the customized buttons?

Tags: android, zooming, android-button

I have an UI in which I am having a WebView and two buttons on top of it.Say,I want to set zooming controls for these two buttons i.e one for zooming in and the other for zooming out.

How will I do this? I know that WebView and MapView do have automatic zoom controls but I want to set them to the buttons which I have created in my UI.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `zoomIn()` and `zoomOut()` on the `WebView` in your buttons onClick listeners.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more please @Anasthase?

Comment: It was so easy @Anasthase.Thanks a lot and here you go +1 and accepted:)

Comment: In your `Activity`, i believe you have retrieved your buttons and webview. On your buttons, add a click listener using `setOnClickListener()`, and within that listener, call `yourWebView.zoomIn()` (or `zoomOut()`).

Comment: Ya I got that by following your way @Anasthase:) Thanks again.